# How to sum array value php

Tags: php

I want all rating values sum then divided with 5

```
  array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[571]
          public 'rating' => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[300]
          public 'rating' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Comment: Start writing code.

Comment: use a ```foreach()``` & extract all the element's value & calculate the Sum. Then divide by 5. Ref - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a 'foreach' block, iterate over each element in your array and sum up its 'rating' value

```
    foreach($array->items as $item) {
    $sum+=(int)$item->rating;            
    } 
    $result = $sum/5;
```

Or you can use the array_sum() method

```
    $sum =array_sum((int)$array->rating);
    $result = $sum/5;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7 solution:

```
$result = array_sum(array_column($array_of_objects, 'rating')) / 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for sum array value using php . First assign variable shich store all sum value so this must set 0 and use loop for make all value sum. this is your code which help you and if your array `$your_array` then

```
$sum = 0; // this is store all sum value so first assign 0
foreach ($your_array as $rating)  {          
{
   $sum += $rating->rating; // sum value with previous value and store it and no need to convert string type to int cause php do it 
}
echo $sum; // this is final value
echo $total_sum = $sum / 5; // this is your desire result
```

and if your array is associative  then use this code

```
$sum = 0; // this is store all sum value so first assign 0
foreach ($your_array as $rating)  {          
{
   $sum += $rating['rating']; // sum value with previous value and store it and no need to convert string type to int cause php do it 
}
echo $sum; // this is final value
echo $total_sum = $sum / 5; // this is your desire result
```

check this code and hope it will help you .

Answer (score -1):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $val){
    $sum += (int) $val->rating;
}
// divide by 5 
$average = $sum/5;
```

for average, I think you should divide sum by no. of result like

```
$average = $sum/count($array);
```