# PHP -> How to sum array values using foreach

Tags: php

I am new developer. I have a problem. 
I want all rating value sum then divided with 5.
foreach show 325. I want result 3+2+5=10 then 10/5=2

```
 foreach ($ratings as $ratingss)  {                          
     echo $ratingss->rating ;
     }
```

**var dump**

```
object(stdClass)[571]
  public 'id' => string '12' (length=2)
  public 'hotel_id' => string '37' (length=2)
  public 'rating' => string '3' (length=1)

object(stdClass)[300]
  public 'id' => string '13' (length=2)
  public 'hotel_id' => string '37' (length=2)
  public 'rating' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Comment: first convert rating to int, at the moment they are string

Comment: No need to convert as PHP will do it itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676118/how-to-sum-array-value-php/43676221#43676221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code. It will sum all values and put in the `$sum` variable.

if your array `object(stdClass)` -> then

```
$sum = 0; // this is store all sum value so first assign 0
foreach ($ratings as $ratingss)          
{
   $sum += $ratingss->rating; // sum value with previous value and store it and no need to convert string type to int cause php do it 
}
echo $sum; // this is final value
echo $final_result = $sum / 5; // this is your desire result
```

if your array -> `associative array` then

```
$sum = 0; // this is store all sum value so first assign 0
foreach ($ratings as $ratingss)           
{
   $sum += $ratingss['rating']; // sum value with previous value and store it and no need to convert string type to int cause php do it 
}
echo $sum; // this is final value
echo $final_result = $sum / 5; // this is your desire result
```

hope this will help you

Comment: And divide the sum by `5`